# Convert equation please

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation I use for sailing but don't know how (or forgot) how to convert the equation to find for $B$
$$
A =  \frac{100 - B}{1.5} + 100
$$
Thanks

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Welcome! Could you show a bit to us what you've tried to transform the equation, and where you get stuck?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I guess it prolly means "how to solve B from this equation of A"

Comment: I want to be able to flip the equation so that it reads B = ...

Comment: $B=100-1.5 (A-100) $

Comment: In general, you may transform both sides of the equation in the same way.  So long as each step you took is reversible (*multiplying by zero isn't reversible for example*) the truth of the final result will be the same as the original.  Begin here by subtracting $100$ from each side to make the side that $B$ is on look a little simpler.  Continue making the side $B$ is on look even simpler by continuing to "undo" all that makes it look more complicated than it should until you are left with just $B$ alone on its side.

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\frac{100-B}{1.5} + 100$$
Subtract $100$ from both sides.
$$A - 100 = \frac{100-B}{1.5}$$
Multiply both sides by $1.5$.
$$\implies (A-100)\cdot 1.5 = 100 -B$$
Move $100$ to the other side, to isolate $B$.
$$B = 100 - (A-100)\cdot 1.5$$
Remove the parenthesis, paying attention to the minus in front.
$$B = 100 - 1.5 A + 150$$
$$B = 250 - 1.5 A$$

Comment: Thanks for showing how you did it too

Comment: @tomI if it helped you, consider marking this as the correct answer.